# C# Should I use lock statement when I am only reading and not changing queue?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, mutex

I am using list as a queue in my multithreading C# application.
I am locking my custom Enqueue and Dequeue methods. Because multiple threads can call those methods.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement
I think I should but I would still ask the question here.
Should I lock Peek method that is only telling me which element is at zero index? 
For the purpose of example consider that I have list(queue) of integers.

```
list = [1, 2, 2, 5]
Enqueue(list, 6)
// [1, 2, 2, 5, 6]

var element = Dequeue(list) // element = 1;
// [2, 2, 5, 6]

var peekElement = Peek(list) // peekElement = 2
// [2, 2, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not use ConcurrentQueue which will do your job easily?

```
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();

queue.Enqueue(1);
queue.Enqueue(2);

if (queue.TryPeek(out int firstValue))
    Console.WriteLine("Peek: " + firstValue);

if (queue.TryDequeue(out int result))
    Console.WriteLine("Dequeue: " + result);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Great solution, didn't know for that structure in msdn. I will assume using ConcurrentQueue.

Answer (score 3):

You should lock.

I imagine that your `Peek()` method looks something like this:

```
public int Peek(List<int> list)
{
    if (list.Length < 1)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Queue is empty");

    return list[0];
}
```

You are expecting it to throw an `InvalidOperationException` with message "Queue is empty" if you try to peek into an empty queue.

But now imagine this scenario with two threads, A and B:

1. Thread A calls Peek() for a list with one element.
2. Thread A executes `if (list.Length < 1)` and determines that the list is not empty, so it won't throw an exception.
3. Thread B calls Dequeue() and empties the list.
4. Thread A moves on to `return list[0]` and whoops - the list is empty so you get a completely different `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I lock Peek method...?

Assuming you don't take Abhay's advice (see other answer) then yes.

The real purpose of locking a lock is to ensure that the thread which has just locked the lock will *see* shared variables in a state that is consistent with how they were left by some other thread that changed them before it released the same lock.

The `list` variable in your example has some internal representation that may be more complicated than just a simple array.  If you allow some thread R to look at the `list` without locking a lock when some other thread W could modify the list at any time, you don't merely risk thread R seeing some out-of-date version of the list; you also risk thread R seeing a *corrupt* version of the list.

Even something as simple as asking for the length of the list could cause thread R to follow a bad pointer and crash the program, or worse.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not.

You should use a modified lock which is not a statement - a MUltipleReaderSingleWriter.

It allows multiple reads, but only ONE write and that only when there is no reader active.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1#thread-safety) of the `Queue<T>` class:

> Public static members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> A [`Queue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1) can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. For a thread-safe queue, see [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1).

So if you call `Peek` from one thread while the queue is modified concurrently by other threads, without synchronizing properly the access to the queue using a `lock` or other means, you are breaking the guarantees offered by the manufacturer of the class. The behavior of the class becomes officially "undefined". This is not a good idea if you are trying to make a program that should be reliable regarding the correctness of its results.